# .NET Deployment Framework

Tags: .net, deployment, automated-deploy

Many people use Nant or Powershell for deployment of their apps to different servers/environments.

These are based on scripting while some solutions allow deployment to be embedded in code like Migrator.Net and other Ruby inspired Db deployment/migration frameworks in .NET.

I was wondering if there are any frameworks for .NET for application deployment that would allow developers to embed full deployment inside code. Things like copying files, creating web apps in IIS, stopping and starting services and so on.

Comment: Have you already considered MSI with Custom Actions, WiX or NSIS installer?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions out there, starting with [setup and deployment projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t%28VS.80%29.aspx) which come with visual studio.

There are other solutions for creating installers, most known are [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) installer and [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks. I think although they tick all the boxes, they are not integrated with the code and that's the solution I'd like to go for.

Comment: @Khash - please explain what you mean by "integrated with the code".

Comment: If you look at Migrator.NET (http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) you will see that the upward and downward migration of database is handled inside the assembly using C# code. This allows the migration steps to be developed and built in the same cycle as the main code rather than a  separate project based on scripting.